# How to Avoid Speech Recognition from Recognizing Speaker Playback in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, aec, echo-cancellation

I am developing a game in Unity that plays human speech through speakers and also performs speech recognition. This will cause the sound played by the speakers to be recognized by the speech recognition, which will lead to inaccurate speech recognition results or even the inability to recognize the correct speech.

I'm using [whisper.unity](https://github.com/Macoron/whisper.unity) for speech recognition.

What are some possible solutions to this problem?

I have only learned about "echo cancellation" through Google search, but I still don't know how to handle it.